# how to pass dictionary statement inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, ordereddictionary

```
comp = {'Bajaj Auto Ltd.':"Bajaj Auto Ltd., Bajaj Auto Ltd, Bajaj Auto, 
Bajaj Auto's, Bajaj Auto Limited"}

comp_name='Bajaj Auto Ltd.'

def findcname(comp_name,data,comp):
    comp=comp
    comp_name=comp[comp_name]

    #data=data[data.Head.str.contains("|".join(list(map(lambda x:x.strip(), 
    #(comp_name.split(','))))),case=False) |                 
    #data.Content.str.contains("|".join(list(map(lambda x:x.strip(), 
    #(comp_name.split(','))))),case=False)]

    data['Company']=list(comp.keys())list(comp.values()).index(comp[comp_name])

    return data

findcname(comp_name,data,comp)





> Output:
> 
> KeyError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-122-37eb04bc7686> in <module>()
>     ----> 1 findcname(comp_name,data,comp)
>     
>     <ipython-input-121-29a90c8a1238> in findcname(comp_name, data, comp)
#>           3     comp_name=comp[comp_name]
#>           4     data=data[data.Head.str.contains("|".join(list(map(lambda 
#                  x:x.strip(),(comp_name.split(','))))),case=False) | 
#                  data.Content.str.contains("|".join(list(map(lambda 
#                  x:x.strip(),(comp_name.split(','))))),case=False)]
>     ----> 5     data['Company']=list(comp.keys())list(comp.values()).index(comp[comp_name])]
>           6     return data
>     
>     KeyError: "Bajaj Auto Ltd., Bajaj Auto Ltd, Bajaj Auto, Bajaj Auto's, 
  Bajaj Auto Limited"
```

Executing error line:

```
(list(comp.keys())[list(comp.values()).index(comp[comp_name])])

> Output:
> 'Bajaj Auto Ltd.'
```

I'm having error in this code, when I'm trying to insert statement inside 
the function, it's showing error or showing dictionary value instead of 
dictionary key. While same line when executed outside function it is working 
perfectly (i.e it is giving dictionary key which is right).

Comment: What does "execute" a dictionary mean? I'm struggling to understand what this code is doing.

Comment: Also, it that a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: You have an extra `]` at the end of the line: `list(comp.values()).index(comp[comp_name])]` and you haven't defined data so very hard to debug your code. The "Executing error line" isn't in your code so not really clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're replacing comp_name in the function with the long string in the line:

```
comp_name=comp[comp_name]
```

which means that `comp_name` here is

```
"Bajaj Auto Ltd., Bajaj Auto Ltd, Bajaj Auto, Bajaj Auto's, Bajaj Auto Limited"
```

while outside the function, it is defined as:

```
comp_name='Bajaj Auto Ltd.'
```

Comment: oh i interchanged those values. Thank you so much for debugging and helping me.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findcname(comp_name,data,comp):
    comp=comp
    #comp_name=comp[comp_name]

    data=data[data.Head.str.contains("|".join(list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),(comp[comp_name].split(','))))),case=False) |  data.Content.str.contains("|".join(list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),(comp[comp_name].split(','))))),case=False)]

    data['Company']=list(comp.keys())list(comp.values()).index(comp[comp_name])

    return data
```

I think this will work perfect now.